# Error while calling stored procedure on linked server

Tags: sql-server

I had configured a linked server to enable the SQL Server Database Engine to execute commands against OLE DB data sources outside of the instance of SQL server by executing sp_addlinkedserver procedure. After doing that I was trying to execute a procedure on a linked server using the following statement

EXEC [LinkedServer].[DatabaseName].[DatabaseOwner].[StoredProcedure] param1, param2

When I tried to execute the statement mentioned above it threw me the following error

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "server name" returned message "Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "server name".

I tried the following

1. Check if a linked server has remote access enabled
2. Increase remote query timeout
3. Check firewall to see if port was enabled.

What am I missing here? I appreciate your help.

Comment: can you execute a simple `SELECT` against that server?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue. (Even though you've checked the port). If you are allowed to disable the firewall temporarily, and give it a quick go.

Comment: I am assuming you're talking about running a select statement for a linked server on the one it is being linked to. Am I right? If yes, then no, I cannot run a select. It gives me the same error message.

Comment: Since you say you've checked the firewall, it seems to be a protocol issue. Try switching to named pipes if currently using TCP

Comment: It was the database login issue. I turned off firewall and test it  and it ran fine. But as soon as I turned on my firewall it threw me following error.  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server returned message "Communication link failure". Msg 121, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

Comment: The problem was with the IPsec..While enabling port I think I forgot about that and enabled it. Disabled and all query runs fine. The linked server is in our domain.